# fgets - Take null character into account

Tags: c, string, stdin, fgets, null-character

When scanning for user input using [`int scanf(const char *format, ...)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm), I would read one less character than the string's size, because the last character of the string has to be the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) `\0`.

```
char str[10];
scanf("%9s", str); /* take \0 into account */
```

But when I use [`char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm), I don't know how I should specify `n`. Most online tutorials set it to `sizeof(str)`, but someone told me that it should be `sizeof(str) - 1`.

So how would I prevent a buffer overflow? Like this:

```
char str[10];
fgets(str, 10, stdin);
```

Or should I do this:

```
char str[10];
fgets(str, 9, stdin);
```

Comment: The first one, fgets uses the last element to null terminate the string if it comes to that. And yes, the recommended usage is `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);`

Comment: @anastaciu Okay thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [C11 7.21.7.2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2) (emphasis mine):

> 2. The `fgets` function **reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n`** [...] A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.
> 3. [if an error occurs] a null pointer is returned.

So, the proper usage is using the full size of the array **and** check the return value.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) /* all bets are off */;
```

Comment: Note: 2 other reasons for returning `NULL`: _end-of-file indicator_ indicator already set and end-of-file occurs before reading any data.